# create four box with hoverover feature

Tags: html, css

I would like to create four boxes (2 on top and two below it), they all have to be in centere of a page when a person hoverover that box it should move a bit and change a box colour. Each boxes should contain some text inside so Option1, option2, option3 and option4: this are my four boxes:

```
    <div class="selectBox" >
    <div class="firstTwoOptions">
        <div class="foo" id="option1" style="background-color:green;"></div>
        <div class="foo" id="option2" style="background-color: black;"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="lastTwoOptions" style="display:block; clear:both;">
        <div class="foo" id="option3"  style="background-color:yellow; "></div>
        <div class="foo" id="option4" style="background-color:blue;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

my CSS:

```
.foo {   
float: left;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
border-width: 1px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: rgba(0,0,0,.2);}
```

Now how do i bring all the boxes to the middle of  a screen, make them toggle and have text inside:
once way to add text inside is by:

```
$("#option1").text("select option one");
```

In here i only get normal text i want text to be in centre of that box, large text and bold.

Comment: Toggle on hover or on click? And... toggle to what?

Comment: Pick one question at a time.

Comment: So it's actually a menu?

Comment: @Paulie_D yes it acts as a menu

Comment: Why do you add text using jQuery and not just in the HTML? The styling like `large text and bold` can be done with CSS.

Comment: @speetje33 using jquery is one way of doing it. yes your right you can use CSS too

Comment: I made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LXX6J/1/), is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: @speetje33 yes thats right! the only thing i want now is when your mouse hover over one of those box it should move and change colour .

Comment: @speetje33, just [a small addition](http://jsfiddle.net/88HQ5/1/) to your fiddle.

Comment: It should move to where? @AndreiV, that's probably better indeed.

Comment: I made a Codepen (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xzEwc) that should get you off to a start.

Comment: @speetje33 I think he wants the boxes to shake. So... animation...

Comment: @User911 I'm glad it is working. Compare your original HTML and CSS with the HTML & CSS from Paulie_D, for future projects :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out:

**HTML**

```
<div class="selectBox">
<div class="firstTwoOptions">
    <div class="foo" id="option1" style="background-color:green;"><p>select option one</p></div>
    <div class="foo" id="option2" style="background-color: black;"><p>select option one</p></div>
</div>
<div class="lastTwoOptions" style="display:block; clear:both;">
    <div class="foo" id="option3" style="background-color:yellow; "><p>select option one</p></div>
    <div class="foo" id="option4" style="background-color:blue;"><p>select option one</p></div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.foo {
float: left;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
border-width: 1px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
text-align:center;
}
.selectBox {
margin:0 auto;
width:425px;
}
.foo p {
display:none;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".foo").hover(function() {
    $(this).find('p').css('display','inline');
    bg = $(this).css('background-color');
    $(this).css('background-color','#FFF');
},function() {
    $(this).find('p').css('display','none');
    $(this).css('background-color',bg);
});
});
```

And here is a **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Karim_AG/uGXwr/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i understand correctly your question and if this will help you
but in this page([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/videma/rK4RW/)) you have four box centered, on mouse hover they change color randomly and the text appears centered on elements
on mouesout text disappears and all elements retrieve the original color
all jQuery code you need is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var colors=['green','black','yellow','blue']
    $('.foo').hover(function(){
        var str = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')'
        $(this).css({'background-color':str}).addClass('rotate')
        },function(defaultColor){
            var ind=$(this).index() 
            $(this).css({'background-color':colors[ind]}).removeClass('rotate')
        })
})
</script>
```

If this solution does not suit your needs, i apologize for making you lose time.